# How to do atrous convolution in tensorflow 2 (tf.keras)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to convert some code from tensorflow 1.x to tensorflow 2.x.
It's been going well so far, but I'm stuck on atrous convolution. Unlike other layers, there doesn't seem to be a one-to-one conversion.

So far, I've been unifying everything to tf.keras. There is a pure keras implementation [here](https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.1/layers/convolutional/#atrousconvolution2d) and a tf.nn.atrous_conv2d implementation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/atrous_conv2d) but I'm also not certain if I can use them in a tf.keras.Model functional api.

Here is the code:

```
with tf.variable_scope('aconv1d_' + name):
        shape = [None, 30, 128]
        kernel = tf.get_variable('kernel', (1, size, shape[-1], n_filters), dtype=tf.float32,
                                 initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        if bias:
            b = tf.get_variable('b', [shape[-1]], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0))
        out = tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(tf.expand_dims(input_tensor, dim=1), kernel, rate=rate, padding='SAME') + (
            b if bias else 0)
        out = tf.squeeze(out, [1])

        return out
```

I would like to just convert this, stick it in the keras functional api, do model.fit, and run.

Thank you for helping out a noob like me.

Comment: You need to use `dilations` parameter in `tf.nn.conv2d` or `dilation_rate` in `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been looking at that too, but how would I do that? 
I want the exact same results and the fact that the inputs are different confuses me. In tf.nn.atrous_conv2d, they take a 4D vector (kernel) as an input, while this is not the case for tf.keras.layers.Conv2D. Thank you again for your time. 

@SusmitAgrawal

Comment: In that case, use `tf.nn.conv2d`. That uses the 4D kernel format you are looking for.

Comment: Can I use that in a keras sequence? I thought that everything had to be done in Keras in order to do a model.fit.

Comment: As long as you use `tf.keras`, TF2 and the functional API / Model subclassing, there shouldn't be any issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atrous Convolution or Dilated Convolution is already available in `tensorflow2.x` version, through the parameter "`dilation_rate`". By default it is set to `(1,1)`, if you look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D. Modifying it to other values , say `(2,2)`, you will get dilated/atrous convolution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is a follow-up question, same as what I commented above but re-commented for your viewing convenience. 

I've been looking at that too, but how would I do that? 
I want the exact same results and the fact that the inputs are different confuses me. In tf.nn.atrous_conv2d, they take a 4D vector (kernel) as an input, while this is not the case for tf.keras.layers.Conv2D. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: It is the case, since if you look attentively at the explanations, you get : input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3) (batch_size,height,width,number_of_channels), so exactly input_shape(4). Also,  please have a look here to know what to do when someone answers your question and it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Are you saying that I can use: 
`tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4,kernel_size = (size, shape[-1]), dillation_rate=rate, initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform())`

to replace 

`tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(tf.expand_dims(input_tensor, dim=1), kernel, rate=rate, padding='SAME')`?

Comment: Also, as for the voting and accepting of solutions: 
I don't have enough reputation quite yet to upvote your answer (I tried to, but I just joined today haha) and I'll be more than happy to accept your solution once I can figure it out. I think I'm very close! Thank you for your patience, and sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: No problem, we are all here to learn! I don't expect you to accept it unless it really helped solved your problem.

Comment: Is this how I would implement it?: `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4,kernel_size = (size, shape[-1]), dillation_rate=rate, initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform())` to replace `tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(tf.expand_dims(input_tensor, dim=1), kernel, rate=rate, padding='SAME')`?